# Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't create any views without getting this error.

I've tried every fix on Stack Overflow, yet nothing works.

The model:

```
 public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

The Controller:

```
 public class ProjectsController : Controller
{
    // GET: Projects
    public ActionResult Project()
    {
        var project = new Project() {Name = "Things" };

        return View();
    }
}
```

When I go into the generated folder "Projects" and create a view I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1980  Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic'
>   because the compiler required type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found.
>   Are you missing a
>   reference?    WebApplication8 C:\Users\mitch\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\Views\Projet.cshtml 1   Active

Comment: Is should be `return View(project);`

Comment: Doesn't work, still got the same error.

Comment: Restart Visual Studio - maybe there is some lock on the folder.

Comment: I tried that a million times, doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some reference version is invalid or doesn't exist, try adding `System.Dynamic.Runtime` reference first.

Secondly,Check your .NET target version and make sure there is no dll you are referencing with higher version, and try closing the visual studio and rebuild after reopen.

Comment: System.Dynamic.Runtime namespace doesnt exist.
Where do I check the .NET target version?

Comment: There is a runtime reference "Antlr3.Runtime" v2.0.50727 that is the only Runtime Reference in the list.

Target Framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Also try changing your .net framework to 4.5 and restart visual studio and rebuild

Comment: changing to 4.5 restarting and rebuilding doesn't work either :/

Comment: Can you delete Antlr reference to identify that the problem is not from it, and if that doesn't fix the problem try adding the reference I stated in the answer even if it not used as a last suggestion I can give you :/

Comment: I've deleted that namespace "Antlr3.Runtime" and still I get the same error.

I've tried adding the namespace System.Dynamic.Runtime but I cant find it anywhere?

Is this a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: Install-Package System.Dynamic.Runtime -Version 4.3.0 it's nuget package

Comment: I've added the nuget package, but when I try to add the reference it can't seem to find it...

Comment: I think you should create other project and check if same problem still exists, as for the nuget package make sure you install it for the required project not for other project from Niger console, sorry if any of this didn't work

Comment: Didnt fix it. I've created a new project, made sure that I installed the Nuget Package for the right project yet it still can't find the reference.

Comment: When I try to compile I get this error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Did you try to find if the Mvc assembly is referenced, What is you visual studio version, it may be a bug in the studio, I suggest you add the steps you follow when creating the project along with screenshots in the answer so others may help :) I hope it works for you